# Change Microsoft Edge Taskbar icon

Tags: taskbar, icons, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How would I change the Taskbar icon for Microsoft Edge. Note that the Edge exe is not double-clickable, so creating a shortcut and changing the icon didn't seem to work for me.

Edit: 
I created shortcut with this path: `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge` and changed the icon. However, when clicking on my icon (white) in Taskbar, it switches to the default icon:

[image]

Comment: Same way you would for anything, a resource hacker.

Comment: The way you would normally change a Taskbar icon does not require a resource hacker. It is built-in functionality.

Comment: How would you usually do it? I'm not sure what the built-in functionality is other than creating your own shortcut.

Comment: That's the functionality to which I'm referring. Create a shortcut. Change the icon. No need for a resource hacker.

Comment: Edge does not open like other programs, for reasons unknown to me yet. Like you said, the exe is not openable by double clicking. Therefore the shortcut created is not directly linked to the exe. I don't think you will be able to change the shortcut icon in the normal way.

Comment: The new Windows 10 is just funny like that! :-) I recognized this because I once tried to do the opposite and create a shortcut on the desktop, but with the blue icon. I got it alright, but the icon was white instead! =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

There is a

> C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\**Assets**

directory that contains images used by Edge. You can replace the blue ones with the black/white ones, or bring your own. After changing the files, you need to **restart** the computer. Also **unpin** and **repin** Microsoft Edge in the taskbar.

They do require **permission** to modify so you would need something like [Take Ownership](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3841-take-ownership-add-context-menu-windows-10-a.html).

If you do this, you don't need to follow the original answer below.

### Original Answer

Create a shortcut on the Desktop and set the address to:

`%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge`
and name it Edge or whatever

Change the icon of the shortcut and then drag the new shortcut to Edge onto your taskbar.

[image: Edge shortcut]

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: There is a `resources.pri` and it references the `Assets` directory. Perhaps you could change the icons in that folder and that will do what you want.

Comment: What's the path to the `Assets` directory?

Comment: It's inside the Edge directory.

Comment: I don't have an assets folder here: `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-microsoftedge_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16397_none_19381f0c8accd5dd` However, I have a bunch of edge icon pngs in that directory. I changed the blue pngs to their white counterparts, but this didn't change the task bar. Where else could it be?

Comment: How did you arrive at that directory? I believe it should be `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.

Comment: I got there by searching for the Edge exe. The changes I made seemed to be reflected into the Assets directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26555/discussion-between-mc10-and-joel-a-christophel).

Comment: Will that get overwritten with an update to the app? I'm trying to do the same thing but for a few store apps...

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this that doesn't require any gp edits or some stuff.

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder
```

1. Paste This in the File Explorer address bar, a window will open with a list of apps
2. Search for MS EDGE (With the Default Logo) and Pin it to your taskbar
3. Right Click on the pinned icon on your taskbar
4. Right Click again on "Microsoft Edge"
5. Click on "Properties"

And then Change Icon to any desired icon you want, doing this won't open a new instance like it did when you might've used a/the solution listed on this website.... if you have any issues with this feel free to reach out to me on Reddit.
Reddit: u/therapistofaliens

Answer (score 0):

Edge Version 105: used Resource Hacker http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/ to open msedge.dll (Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\105...), replaced the default icon (Action>Replace Icon>101), saved a copy of msedge.dll, move altered .dll into the original directory. Taskbar icon updated.

Comment: Please explain your answer, so that others can understand what you mean